# 404 Not Found error with streamsend API when trying to Import

Tags: api, stream, http-status-code-404

I successfully uploaded a file to StreamSend got the upload ID. Using the upload id i am trying to import the details. Below is the URL i am using

https://app.streamsend.com/audiences/1/imports

Below is the XML i am posting to the above URL

```
<import>
  <reactivate>false</reactivate>
  <lists>7</lists>
  <upload-id>{17}</upload-id>
  <separator>Tab</separator>
  <columns>
    <column>email_address</column>
  </columns>
</import>
```

I am unable to do an import while posting to the above URL. Is there any problem with the server? I am getting 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value for the upload-id element must be given with out the brackets {}.

This change resolved the issue. I am still unable to understand why this error resulted in 404 Not found error.